# Exponent syntax in Python

Tags: python, math, compiler-errors, operators, exponent

I am used to writing `e^10` in several languages. However, every time in my short time writing Python I end up with this type error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'

Since in Python we should use `**`. What made Python choose that operator instead of the `^`, which, *I think*, is more frequently used in programming and is more natural to my mind.

Comment: @Selcuk damn it that title, that's why I couldn't find it when posting the question, thank you!

Comment: Also I don't think that `^` is the power operator in C++ either.

Comment: @Selcuk yeah, I edited, missed that too, sorry!

Comment: @gsamaras No worries, the Stack Overflow search function really sucks. Even when you type in the exact title of a question, it won't always find the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^` is already taken as `exclusive or` in python. So `**` was the better alternative.

Comment: Oh OK. Take a look at the duplicate Selcuk mentioned, so that you might want to merge your answer with the top answer there.

Comment: @gsamaras, Is there a way to merge answers?

Comment: Moses not for you. What I mean is that the top answer from the dupe mentions that it was based on older language. I would edit my answer, if I were you, so that it contains that information too, making it more complete, than every other answer on SO today. BTW, do you think that my question is so bad to have a negative score? :/

Comment: @gsamaras I think questions get downvoted when the community thinks the questioner did not show enough research effort.

Comment: Not only that, there are more reasons to downvote. However I am asking you now. You see, I searched for the duplicate, but I just could not find it with that title (I had commented about that, but the comment was removed)!